# Sorting values in mixed columns and dropping duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with several columns, which I have sorted based on multiple columns. They include datasets that have been worked on several times and then concatenated into one dataframe. Therefore, several rows are duplicates, but some have new information (but the new information has not to be in the newest reworking of the dataset). I need the dataset without duplicates with the information in the column `translation` , if there is one.

My first step was to sort the dataframe by multiple columns. I then wanted to drop the duplicates keeping the last, so I used the  `na_position = 'first'` :

`df = df.sort_values(by=['message_timestamp', 'message', 'chat_id', 'translation'], na_position = 'first')`

Yet, because the column `translation` includes integers, strings and NaN, it does always put the translation in the last row of each 'group' (so rows belonging together), but when the translation only contains integers, it has the translation of the integer in the first row.

So, the table I get after sorting looks like this:

| index | message_timestamp | message | translation | chat_id | other col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-08-09 12:00 | Hello |  | 2348 | data |
| 2 | 2015-08-09 12:00 | Hello |  | 2348 | data |
| 3 | 2015-08-09 12:00 | Hello | Hallo | 2348 | data |
| 4 | 2017-08-09 16:00 | Where is it? |  | 3456 | data2 |
| 5 | 2019-08-09 14:00 | Thanks |  | 4575 | data |
| 6 | 2015-04-09 12:00 | 38 | 38 | 5342 | data2 |
| 7 | 2015-04-09 12:00 | 38 |  | 5342 | data2 |
| 8 | 2019-08-09 12:00 | Hello |  | 3243 | data |
| 9 | 2015-08-14 13:00 | number 4 |  | 8678 | data |
| 10 | 2015-08-14 13:00 | number 4 | Nummer 4 | 8678 | data |

I wanted to use this code to drop the duplicates:

`result = df.drop_duplicates(subset=(['message_timestamp', 'message', 'chat_id', 'other col']), keep='last')`

but I loose the integers in the translation, because they have their translation in the first row.

The result should be:

| index | message_timestamp | message | translation | chat_id | other col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2015-08-09 12:00 | Hello | Hallo | 2348 | data |
| 4 | 2017-08-09 16:00 | Where is it? |  | 3456 | data2 |
| 5 | 2019-08-09 14:00 | Thanks |  | 4575 | data |
| 6 | 2015-04-09 12:00 | 38 | 38 | 5342 | data2 |
| 8 | 2019-08-09 12:00 | Hello |  | 3243 | data |
| 10 | 2015-08-14 13:00 | number 4 | Nummer 4 | 8678 | data |

I've also tried to convert the column `translation` to string, but this does not help with sorting.

Does someone has an idea how to solve my problem? Thank you all very much in advance!

**Edit:** There are some messages without translation that have to be preserved in the result - I've therefore edited the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html?highlight=ffill#pandas.DataFrame.ffill), grouping on message-timestamp, in the translation column and then drop-duplicates, preserving the integer value in translation column

````
df['translation']=df.groupby(['message_timestamp'])['translation'].ffill()
df.drop_duplicates(subset=(['message_timestamp', 'message', 'chat_id', 'other col']), keep='last').fillna('')```
````

```
    index   message_timestamp   message     translation chat_id other col
2       3   2015-08-09 12:00    Hello        Hallo      2348    data
3       4   2017-08-09 16:00    Where is it?            3456    data2
4       5   2019-08-09 14:00    Thanks                  4575    data
6       7   2015-04-09 12:00    38           38         5342    data2
7       8   2019-08-09 12:00    Hello                   3243    data
9      10   2015-08-14 13:00    number 4     Nummer 4   8678    data
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - unfortunately it does not function because there are some rows without a translation. I've edited the tables in the example above to make it clear.

Comment: As I've written in my answer to PaulS: It does work on the example table I've provided in the question, but unfortunately it does not work at all in my real data set. Neither the string translations nor the integers in the translation column are filled in. I'm really desperate in finding the reason for this. I have empty values also in other columns - could this be a reason why it does not fill in? Or that the empty values are not all NaN (some show nan in the column, some are simple empty). Do you have an idea how I could figure out the problem?

Comment: @athelas, the provided solutions are based on the provided sample and the expected output. I did provided the explanation of the solution as well. If you provide some details on the data you're challenged with, one can help out. Further, in which scenarios this solution fails? can you share that?

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem is that the dataframe has 20.000 rows and 17 columns, so it isn't easy to find the reason why the code isn't working. I'm trying to find the errors and to adapt my data example. Thank you for you effort to help me.

Comment: Sorry, I found the error in my dataset - it was caused by a mixture of NaN-values and simple empty spaces, that's why the integers weren't in the right order after sorting. Thank you for your help, all your answers worked with the example data I've provided. I choose this answer as solution because it is very clear and concise.

Comment: Thanks @athelas for accepting , please consider to upvote to make solution bubble up. I’m glad your question is addressed

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, based on the idea of filling the missing values with [`pandas.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [`pandas.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html), and then dropping the duplicates with [`pandas.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
(df.groupby('message_timestamp', group_keys=True)
 .apply(lambda g: g.bfill().ffill())
 .reset_index(drop=True)
 .drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns[1:]))
```

Output:

```
   index message_timestamp   message translation  chat_id other col
0      4  2015-04-09 12:00        38          38     5342     data2
2      1  2015-08-09 12:00     Hello       Hallo     2348      data
5      6  2015-08-14 13:00  number 4    Nummer 4     8678      data
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - unfortunately it does not function because there are some rows without a translation. I've edited the tables in the example above to make it clear.

Comment: I guess my solution also works well on your new dataset! I have you checked that, @athelas?

Comment: It does work on the example table I've provided in the question, but unfortunately it does not work at all in my real data set. Neither the string translations nor the integers in the translation column are filled in. I'm really desperate in finding the reason for this. I have empty values also in other columns - could this be a reason why it does not fill in? Or that the empty values are not all NaN (some show nan in the column, some are simple empty). Do you have an idea how I could figure out the problem?

Comment: Without seeing your dataset is quite difficult to identify the cause of the problem, @athelas! I would suggest you sampling your data to obtain a small dataset exhibiting the problem. After that, please share that small dataset with us, so that we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I found the error in my dataset - it was caused by a mixture of NaN-values and simple empty spaces, that's why the integers weren't in the right order after sorting. Thank you for your help, all your answers worked with the example data I've provided. I choose Naveed's answer as solution because it is very clear and concise and easy to understand.

Comment: Great, @athelas, that you have fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution by using [**`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) :

```
df['translation'] = df['translation'].astype(str)

out = (df.sort_values(by=['message_timestamp', 'translation'], ascending=False)
         .drop_duplicates(subset=(['message_timestamp', 'message', 'chat_id', 'other col']), keep='last')
         .sort_index()
         .reset_index(drop=True)
       )
```

##### # Output :

```
  message_timestamp   message translation  chat_id other col
0    09-08-15 12:00     Hello       Hallo     2348      data
1    09-04-15 12:00        38          38     5342     data2
2    14-08-15 13:00  number 4    Nummer 4     8678      data
```